# Spring MVC, Hibernate - JDBC Connection closed, Transaction resolution unknown

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions, hibernate-search

I'm indexing MySQL tables with Hibernate Search and it takes some time. After that Exceptions are thrown:

> Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from
>   the server was 239 757 milliseconds ago.
>
> The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 30 milliseconds ago.
>
> Could not commit
>   Hibernate transaction Communications link failure during commit().
>   Transaction resolution unknown.

Indexing is done in a method annotated with @Transactional(readOnly = true) .

MySQL server has in my.cnf directive: *wait_timeout = 60*.

How can I instruct Spring/Hibernate to not close active transaction?
I'm using HikariCP as a dataSource.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you actually post the full stack trace(s)? Also it looks like you are dealing with a database setup/communication error. Not so much to do with Hibernate Search. Have you seen this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql? How do your connection settings look like?

Comment: Thank you for the link, I haven't seen it before. I've changed wait_timeout to 3 hours and error disappeared. But I don't like this solution so I will try some tips from your link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the HikariCP `idleTimeout` and `maxLifetime` to something less than your my.cnf timeouts.  See the answer in the [HikariCP FAQ](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/FAQ#q-i-am-getting-a-commysqljdbcexceptionsjdbc4communicationsexception-communications-link-failure-exception-logged-in-the-isconnectionalive-method-of-hikaripool-in-my-logs-what-is-happening).